# Obtaining a submatrix from a squared matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, submatrix

I want to find a way to obtain a submatrix from an initial bigger squared matrix in c , more specifically , the bottom right submatrix . Then i want the for cycle to give me all the submatrix that i can obtain from the original squared matrix.

I found some code online :

```
int initial_matrix[3][3]
int submatrix[2][2];
for( int i = 0; i < R - r + 1; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < C - c + 1; j++){
    submatrix[i][j]=initial_matrix[i][j]
  }
}
```

where :

- `R` is the number of rows of the initial matrix (so in this case `R=3`)
- `C` is the number of columns of the initial matrix (so in this case `C=3`)
- `r` is the number of rows of the submatrix that i want to obtain (so in this case `r=2`)
- `c` is the number of columns of the submatrix that i want to obtain (so in this case `c=2`)

But this cycle only gives me the upper left submatrix , while I want the bottom right and then expand it so that it gives me all the possible submatrix of the initial matrix.

Comment: Have you copied that code correctly? Do you see where it is missing semicolons?

Comment: Do not try to program by finding code online. Do you know what `submatrix[i][j]=initial_matrix[i][j]` does? Which element in `submatrix` does it write to? Which element in `initial_matrix` does it read from? Which element do you want it to read from?

Comment: What is the context here? Are learning to program in C and this is an exercise? Do you not know how to program in C and you are trying to find some code to solve a problem?

Comment: This sentence does not make sense: “Then i want the for cycle to give me all the submatrix that i can obtain from the original squared matrix.”

Comment: You could use two variables that hold the offset of the sub-matrix in from position [0;0] to the position that should be the upper left corner of the submatrix and use these to calculate the position in the bigger matrix.

Answer (score 2):

At first your indices in the loops are not correct! You want to fill in your target matrix rows from indices `0` to `r` and columns from indices `0` to `c` so your loops need to look like:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < r; ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < c; ++j)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

From here on you now can simply assign your target matrix at indices `i` and `j`:

```
submatrix[i][j] = ...;
```

Problem is that these are *not* the same indices as in your source matrix (unless you want to use the top-left corner submatrix), so you need to translate the indices to the appropriate positions within the source matrix. Luckily, this is not difficult; if the top-left corner of the submatrix within the source matrix is at row `r0` and column `c0` then you simply need to add these to the corresponding loop indices, thus you get:

```
... = initial_matrix[r0 + i][c0 + j];
```

In your case this would mean e.g. `[1 + i][1 + j]` to get the bottom-right submatrix with both `i` and `j` counting up from 0 to excluded 2 (i.e. counting 0 and 1).